# Create SpreadSheet without Google Drive Scope

Tags: python, google-api, spreadsheet, gspread

Is there any way to create spreadsheet only using the scope `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets` in Gspread?

Based on the documentation, seems like that scope itself can handle "create":

[image: Google scope documentation]

Please suggest the example code or web related to this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can cretae a spreadsheet using Google API with just one of the following scopes:

- `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive`
- `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file`
- `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets`

Source: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/create

---

The Google Drive permission scope is only required if you intent to save the file to a specific folder. Otherwise, you can save to root directly with just the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets` scope.

Although it is possible to pass in custom scopes in GSpread:

```py
# Use one of the following, depends on your use case
gspread.oauth(scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'])
gspread.service_account(scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'])
```

Source: https://docs.gspread.org/en/latest/api/top-level.html

---

However, in the source code: https://github.com/burnash/gspread/blob/50b910f2911c6203e139934bafbbce9fe300e8e1/gspread/client.py#L228

It used the [Google Drive's `create` API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create) to create the Spreadsheet instead of using Google Sheets API, that's why it will require the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive` scope

Comment: I got this error that why i am asking: gspread.exceptions.APIError: {'code': 403, 'message': 'Request had insufficient authentication scopes.', 'errors': [{'message': 'Insufficient Permission', 'domain': 'global', 'reason': 'insufficientPermissions'}], 'status': 'PERMISSION_DENIED', 'details': [{'@type': 'type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo', 'reason': 'ACCESS_TOKEN_SCOPE_INSUFFICIENT', 'domain': 'googleapis.com', 'metadata': {'method': 'google.apps.drive.v3.DriveFiles.Create', 'service': 'drive.googleapis.com'}}]}This error coming from
gs = gspread.authorize(cred);
sh = gs.create(name)

Comment: Hi @RenardiAdryantoroPriambudi, unfortunately this is an issue in GSpread code, refer to my edited answer above.